# How can I maximize cache size for <webview>s inside a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, caching, webview, google-chrome-app

I have a number of webviews inside a Chrome Packaged App, each playing, or ready to play, a video.  I want to get the best possible quality of playback, and I want to be able to start playback of any video as quickly, precisely and smoothly as possible.  So, I want each webview to cache its video.

I believe there is a 5MB per webview limit, and a 260 MB total limit for all webviews, although I have not been able to track down where I got that idea from when I was working on this many months ago.

I also thought there was a way to increase the 5MB limit.  The closest I have been able to find is at:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-html5/6RHxi5BdKO4
and
http://learnfrommike.blogspot.ca/2012/07/google-chrome-application-cache-5mb.html
but I am unable to find the Quota table they talk about, and I am unsure if this is what I am looking for as there seem to be multiple caches and limits in a Chrome App.

How can I maximize the cache size used by each webview?

Comment: Are you asking about the webview storage partition or some other kind of browser storage? There is a bunch of information about browser storage and quotas [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/). The webview [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#partition]) doesn't mention a limit for partitions.